# Bash prompt after format of drives

Tags: bash, uefi, format

I'm almost certain I formatted all my partitions to unallocated space, yet on an occasional reboot back to windows 10, I get thrown to a bash prompt.  So I have to reboot and select windows boot manager.  What am I doing wrong?  Did I simply think I formatted all the partitions or is this boot manager going in a place I cannot reach by a simple format?

(I've never liked working with grub or boot manager, especially combined, it never makes much sense to me)

Answer (score 0):

So you formatted the the partitions of ubuntu os. But still have entry in the boot menu. No Problem,You can use EasyBCD to remove the boot option. It have free non-commercial license for personal use. The instructions to use the software are also available on the site.

http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1
                  OR

Windows button +R to launch RUN. Enter "msconfig" and press enter. Select boot tab. Delete All entries other than the windows 10.

Comment: Msconfig only shows Windows 10 as a boot option

Comment: Have you tried EasyBCD. It can certainly solve the problem

Comment: Easybcd says I'm booting in EFI mode it says nothing of grub or bash command prompt

Comment: I just did something really simple, checked the partitions of the drives to see I was oblivious in the first place.  I could have sworn I formatted them but I did not, there were several partitions with an operating system.  I'll have to remove them.  Sorry for the trouble.